# Complete Regex to match url with port number

Tags: regex

I need this regular expression:

`(https?:\/\/(?:w{1,3}.)?[^\s]*?(?:\.[a-z]+)+)(?![^<]*?(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>))`

to match this pattern http://localhost:3000 or any url that has a port number.

Link to rubular https://rubular.com/r/tkCOv181H2KJtU

Comment: Are you looking to validate URLs or just search for URL-like strings?

Comment: [`https?:\/\/[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*(:\d+)?(?:\/[a-z\d]+)*`](https://rubular.com/r/mWpatwcvuFKHv0)

Comment: Make the port part optional `https?:\/\/(?:w{1,3}\.)?[^\s.]*(?:\.[a-z]+)+(?::\d+)?(?![^<]*(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>))` https://regex101.com/r/Yx6qJZ/1

Comment: That works. Make it an answer and I will validate it.

Comment: It is actually still not matching the pattern http://localhost:3000

Comment: @LoudghiriAhmed I have updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things to note in the pattern.

You have to escape the dot to match it literally in this part `(?:w{1,3}\.)?`

If you add the dot to the character class `[^\s.]*` you don't have to make it a non greedy quantifier.

You can omit the outer capturing group if you want the match only.

You could make the port part optional `(?::\d+)?` to match it:

```
https?:\/\/(?:w{1,3}\.)?[^\s.]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*(?::\d+)?(?![^<]*(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>))
```

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/rOW6BInGZ78qRM)

Comment: The patter http://localhost:3000 is not a match with this Regexp https://rubular.com/r/ArkswxZDanykvK

Comment: @LoudghiriAhmed I forgot a quantifier. Like this `https?:\/\/(?:w{1,3}\.)?[^\s.]*(?:\.[a-z]+)*(?::\d+)?(?![^<]*(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>))` https://rubular.com/r/aD3ihZWBhm6Mvd

Comment: `https://www.google.com/test/` does not match the pattern with this Regexp

Comment: I think your original pattern also does not match that. The pattern depends on what you would accept to match.

Comment: But you could for example extend it to  repeat matching word chars and forward slashes `https?:\/\/(?:w{1,3}\.)?[^\s.]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*(?::\d+)?(?:\/\w+)*\/?(?![^<]*(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>))` 
 https://rubular.com/r/RejF1KoE7xsgjs

Comment: How to update this RegExp to accept urls with '-' character. E.g https://google.com/test-bonj link to rubular: https://rubular.com/r/RejF1KoE7xsgjs

Comment: To accept also '-' characters I updated the Regexp to `https?:\/\/(?:w{1,3}\.)?[^\s.]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*(?::\d+)?((?:\/\w+)|(?:-\w+))*\/?(?![^<]*(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>))`

Comment: @Theforthbird I updated the Regexp it looks like it's working. Look at my comment

Comment: @LoudghiriAhmed The pattern works indeed. If I could make a suggestion, it would be writing this part with the alternation `((?:\/\w+)|(?:-\w+))*` using an unroll the loop variant `(?:\/\w+(?:-\w+)*)*` like `https?:\/\/(?:w{1,3}\.)?[^\s.]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*(?::\d+)?(?:\/\w+(?:-\w+)*)*(?![^<]*(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>))` See https://rubular.com/r/Ex7NjbEuhvhrOB

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the Regular expression that matches the requirements is:

`https?:\/\/(?:w{1,3}\.)?[^\s.]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*(?::\d+)?((?:\/\w+)|(?:-\w+))*\/?(?![^<]*(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>))`

This expression includes the following characters in the url:

- '/'
- '-'
- '_'

https://rubular.com/r/7BjXQP6vaA7hvM